# How not to create duplicate Spring Boot application log files?

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, logging, log4j, init.d

**Situation**

1. I use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to create executable `jar` package of my Spring Boot application.
   Application is at server (Ubuntu) managed via `init.d` service:

> /etc/init.d/{appname} start|stop

2. I use `Log4j` `RollingFile` appender to create hourly log files (`application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz`) located in my application directory.

**Problem**

There is a duplicated application log file located in `/var/log/{appname}.log`.

**Question**

How do not create duplicated log file in `/var/log`?

---

**log4j.xml**

```
<RollingFile name="appFileAppender" fileName="./logs/application.log" filePattern="application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %X{correlationId} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

File `pom.xml` is not connected to this issue in any way.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml

Comment: ...and log4j configuration, obviously

Comment: Added `log4j.xml` rolling file appender configuration but this issues would be rather connected how `init.d` service works.

Comment: share your entire log4j.xml configuration.  You're probably also transitively including the default file appender that's defined in org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml